# Mysql IN keyword

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I am trying to write a query using the IN keyword.

Table A
  attrId, attrName

Table B
  key, attrId, attrVal

Based on key provided, I want to return the all attrName, attrVal combinations. The result will contain of columns from both tables. I don't want to use join using attrId as I trying to practice the usage of IN keyword.

Below is the query that I have attempted:

```
Select a.attrName, b2.attrVal
from table_A AS a, table_B AS b2
where a.attrId in (Select b1.attrId from Table_B b1 where key = <someKey>)
```

However I am not getting any result for the query. Also are queries that use IN keyword slow and should be avoided.  I have approx 500 entries in table_A and 500k entries in table_B. The other alternative for me is to fetch all attrId from table_B and then fire multiple jdbc queries for each attrId retrieved to get corresponding attrName.
Can you please help out? 
Thanks

Comment: with 500 entries in A, and 500k in B - you are processing 250 million rows in total by cross joining them. are you sure that's what you are trying to do?

Comment: As mentioned, based on key given I want to return the all attrName, attrVal combinations. Along with key, the user **may or may not** provide attrNames. If he does not provide attrName, return all attrName, attrVal combinations associated with key. If user specifies attrNames (e.g two attrNames), then I want to return only those 2 attrNmes and their attrValues.  I do realise I would be traversing alot of rows and thus am looking for an alternative.

Comment: `IN ( SELECT ... )` optimizes very poorly; a `JOIN` is usually much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is performing a CROSS JOIN operation, every row returned from `a` is being "matched" with every row from `b`.

Your query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT a.attrName
     , b2.attrVal
  FROM table_A a
 CROSS
  JOIN table_B b2
 WHERE a.attrId IN ( <some_list> )
```

The only way this query doesn't return any rows are 1) no rows in `a` satisfy the predicate in the `WHERE` clause, 2) b2 contains no rows, or 3) execution of the query is generating so many rows that it exceeds some available resource (e.g. temporary space) and returns an error, or 4) the client has timed out or cancelled the query before it completes.

I understand you are attempting to write a query that uses the use the `IN` operator, but the set returned by the query you posted really doesn't make much sense.

---

**Q:** are queries that use IN keyword slow and should be avoided.

**A:** The `IN` operator itself does not necessarily make a query slow.

For example:

```
SELECT t.id FROM mytable t WHERE t.id = 2 OR t.id = 3 OR t.id = 5
```

Could be rewritten using the `IN` operator as:

```
SELECT t.id FROM mytable t WHERE t.id IN (2,3,5)
```

On the other hand, a query using the `IN` operator with a correlated subquery can be "slow" if either 1) the subquery is slow and/or 2) there's a lot of rows that the subquery has to be evaluated for.

---

If you want to return rows from `b` that meet some condition, and then match those to rows in `a`, you should avoid a `CROSS JOIN` operation, by supplying some condition for the match (a join predicate in the `ON` clause)

For example:

```
SELECT a.attrName
     , b.attrVal
  FROM table_A a
  JOIN table_B b
    ON a.attrId = b.attrId
 WHERE b.key = '<someKey>'
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I just added a comment above to explain what I am trying to achieve. I agree cross join would not be best option for me and hence am looking out for an alternative. Can you please suggest one

Comment: Cross join is not just "not the best option", it is the "wrong option".  See his final example.

Comment: @RickJames: My answer should have made that more clear. (I'm thinking that I should have highlighted the point that the OP's use of the old-school **comma notation** for the join operation was the **same thing** as a **CROSS JOIN** (given there are no join predicates in the query.) There's a few oddball corner cases where a CROSS JOIN might be the right option...  I should have done a better job explaining that interjecting an `IN` operator into a statement, for the sake of "using an `IN` keyword", that just strikes me as nonsensical.

Comment: @Sam123: The query example at the end of my answer should return the resultset you specified. There's no need for a subquery. That same result could be produced by different query patterns, but the JOIN pattern (as shown in the example usually gives the best performance.